# Java 8 CompletableFuture lazy computation control

Tags: java, java-8, lazy-evaluation, completable-future

I've got a question about [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and its possible usage for lazy computations.

It seems like it is a great substitute for `RunnableFuture` for this task since it is possible to easily create task chains and to have total control of each chain link. Still I found that it is very hard to control when exactly does the computation take place.

If I just create a `CompletableFuture` with `supplyAssync` method or something like that, it is OK. It waits patiently for me to call `get` or `join` method to compute. But if I try to make an actual chain with `whenCompose`, `handle` or any other method, the evaluation starts immediately, which is very frustrating.

Of course, I can always place some blocker task at the start of the chain and release the block when I am ready to begin calculation, but it seems a bit ugly solution. Does anybody know how to control when does `CompletableFuture` actually run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a conceptual difference between `RunnableFuture` and `CompletableFuture` that you're missing here.

- `RunnableFuture` implementations take a task as input and hold onto it. It runs the task when you call the `run` method.
- A `CompletableFuture` does not hold onto a task. It only knows about the result of a task. It has three states: **complete**, **incomplete**, and **completed exceptionally** (failed).

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` is a factory method that gives you an incomplete `CompletableFuture`. It also schedules a task which, when it completes, will pass its result to the `CompletableFuture`'s `complete` method. In other words, the future that `supplyAsync` hands you doesn't know anything about the task, and can't control when the task runs.

To use a `CompletableFuture` in the way you describe, you would need to create a subclass:

```
public class RunnableCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> implements RunnableFuture<T> {
    private final Callable<T> task;

    public RunnableCompletableFuture(Callable<T> task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            complete(task.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to start `CompletableFuture` when I need it, but to prevent it from starting when I don't need it to. Your example does the same thing I am trying to do now (since I don not know how to do it better), namely putting some trigger at the beginning of the chain.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. By itself, the `CompletableFuture` does not "start". It's the `supplyAsync` factory method that starts the task. If you use `supplyAsync` method, you can't control when the task starts. In my answer I'm trying to offer a method to create a `CompletableFuture` from a task without using `supplyAsync`.

Comment: I do understand, I just hoped, that there is a better solution. Currently I just created a controller class that contains empty `CompletableFuture` which should be placed at the beginning of the chain. Now in order to start the chain, I need just to "complete" it. Also I can cancel the whole chain before it even started.

Answer (score 9):

CompletableFuture is a push-design, i.e. results are pushed down to dependent tasks as soon as they become available. This also means side-chains that are not in themselves consumed still get executed, which can have side-effects.

What you want is a pull-design where ancestors would only be pulled in as their data is consumed.
This would be a fundamentally different design because side-effects of non-consumed trees would never happen.

Of course with enough contortions CF could be made to do what you want, but you should look into the fork-join framework instead which allows you to only run the computations you depend on instead of pushing down results.

Comment: Indeed I do need a pull-design, but I do not know where to get it. Currently I do not want to write the whole execution infrastructure by myself, so I am trying to use existing classes. In future I will probably think about it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of dealing with your problem is wrapping your CompletableFuture in something with a lazy nature. You could use a Supplier or even Java 8 Stream.

Answer (score 0):

it is late, but how about using constructor for first CompletableFuture in the chain?

```
CompletableFuture<Object> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();

// compose the chain
cf.thenCompose(sometask_here);

// later starts the chain with
cf.complete(anInputObject);
```