# How to flatten a list inside a stream of completable futures?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future

I have this:

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>>
```

how can I convert it to

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<Item>>
```

Where: the second stream is comprised of each and all the Items inside each of the lists in the first stream.

I looked into `thenCompose` but that solves a completely different problem which is also referred to as "flattening".

How can this be done efficiently, in a streaming fashion, without blocking or prematurely consuming more stream items than necessary?

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PARALLELISM);
    Stream<CompletableFuture<List<IncomingItem>>> reload = ... ;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    CompletableFuture<List<IncomingItem>> allFutures[] = reload.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    CompletionService<List<IncomingItem>> queue = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(pool);
    for(CompletableFuture<List<IncomingItem>> item: allFutures) {
        queue.submit(item::get);
    }
    List<IncomingItem> THE_END = new ArrayList<IncomingItem>();
    CompletableFuture<List<IncomingItem>> ender = CompletableFuture.allOf(allFutures).thenApply(whatever -> {
        queue.submit(() -> THE_END);
        return THE_END;
    });
    queue.submit(() -> ender.get());
    Iterable<List<IncomingItem>> iter = () -> new Iterator<List<IncomingItem>>() {
        boolean checkNext = true;
        List<IncomingItem> next = null;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(checkNext) {
                try {
                    next = queue.take().get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                checkNext = false;
            }
            if(next == THE_END || next == null) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public List<IncomingItem> next() {
            if(checkNext) {
                hasNext();
            }
            if(!hasNext()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            checkNext = true;
            return next;
        }
    };
    Stream<IncomingItem> flat = StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false).flatMap(List::stream);
```

This works at first, unfortunately, it has a fatal bug: the resulting stream seems to terminate prematurely, before retrieving all the items.

**2023 UPDATE**

Four years later, I still have not chosen an answer, because both answers at the moment are saying this is "impossible". That doesn't sound right. I'm simply asking for an efficient way to take items that are completed in batches and be able to monitor their completion individually. Perhaps this is easier with Virtual Threads in Java 21? I no longer maintain this codebase but the question remains a great unsolved problem.

Update#2: Clarification of assumptions

`CompletableFuture` *represents a future result of an asynchronous computation* according to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/completablefuture-in-java/ ... interestingly the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) are not quite as clear.

Update#3:

Performance is not the focus of the question, only efficiency, in a specific sense: if task 1 takes T1 to complete and task 2 takes T2 to complete, then waiting for a total of `max(T1,T2)` time for completion is more efficient than waiting for `T1+T2` time. Then extend that to `N`-sized lists of tasks `T, U, V, ...`, and it probably looks something like `max(T1..Tn)+max(U1..Un)+max(V1..Vn)` or hopefully `max(T1..Vn)`. Assuming the same N for all lists here is only an explanatory simplification (really should be `I`, `J`, `K`...). In other words, please assume that the asynchronous tasks which are represented in the Stream of Lists are I/O bound, not CPU-bound. This can be simulated by inserting random `Thread.sleep()` if you wish to demonstrate something in code. Apologies for the sloppy notation - I have a background in Computer Science but it's been a while since I've tried to formally describe a problem like this.

**Update#4**

Based on the answer from @Slaw, I can see that the core problem I was facing is the mismatch between *stream arrival order* (the order in which futures are provided through the `Stream`) and *future completion order* (the order in which each `CompletableFuture` completes execution and unlocks the `List` within it). So a **new revised TL;DR** for this question is: *How can you take a `Stream` that's produced in arbitrary order, and re-order it into futures execution completion order, so that a `flatMap()` operation will not block unnecessarily?*

Comment: You can't. If this would be possible, you would know how many items each future would yield. What is possible is to turn it into a `CompletableFuture<Stream<Item>>`.

Comment: I have submitted a solution that meets the requirements listed. Please read it in its entirety, as it has some important details and unintuitive points.

Comment: As others have said, it's only possible if you know the list sizes in advance. Otherwise there's no way to know whether a given future is waiting on the current list or the next list in the source stream. Unless you're willing to wait on each list before proceeding to the next. Or if order doesn't matter at all, you can stream each list as it's returned.

Comment: @AlexR So, what is the actual requirement? Do you want to see a coding approach in JDK 21?

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of the elements (order within the list and/or order of the lists themselves)?

Comment: @Holger no, I do not. The only order that matters is to be able to process the task results in completion order for the purpose of avoiding unnecessary blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which not only avoids blocking, by preferring to process already completed futures, it even retains lazy processing of the original stream, as far as possible. As long as there are completed futures among the already encountered futures it will not advance in the source traversal.

This is best demonstrated by an example using an *infinite* source which still can complete in finite time (and quite fast due to the preference of completed futures).

```java
Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>> streamOfFutures = Stream.generate(
    () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(10, 0, 200).boxed().toList(),
        CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(5), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
);
System.out.println(flattenResults(streamOfFutures)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .anyMatch(i -> i == 123)
);
```

The implementation will process already completed futures immediately on encounter. Only if the future has not been completed yet, a queuing action will be chained and the pending counter increased. Care must be taken to decrease the counter even on exceptional completion and to queue an item (an empty list), to unblock the consumer thread in case it’s taking an element right at this point. The exception will be propagated to the caller when encountered. Like with short-circuiting parallel streams, it’s possible to miss errors if the result is found before processing all elements.

If the terminal operation is short-circuiting and finishes without processing the entire stream, the counter is irrelevant and the operation will not wait for the completion of pending futures. Only when the source stream has been traversed completely, the counter becomes relevant for detecting when all futures have been completed.

```java
static <T> Stream<T> flattenResults(Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> stream) {
    Spliterator<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> srcSp = stream.spliterator();
    BlockingQueue<List<T>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
                                                 srcSp.estimateSize(), 0) {
        final AtomicLong pending = new AtomicLong();
        Spliterator<T> fromCurrentList;
        Throwable failure;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if(checkExisting(action)) return true;

            while(srcSp.tryAdvance(this::checkNew)) {
                if(checkExisting(action)) return true;
            }

            return checkAfterSourceExhausted(action);
        }
        private boolean checkExisting(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            for(;;) {
                var sp = fromCurrentList;
                if(sp == null) {
                    List<T> newList = queue.poll();
                    if(newList == null) return false;
                    fromCurrentList = sp = newList.spliterator();
                }
                if(sp.tryAdvance(action)) return true;
                fromCurrentList = null;
            }
        }

        private void checkNew(CompletableFuture<List<T>> f) {
            if(f.isDone()) fromCurrentList = f.join().spliterator();
            else {
                pending.incrementAndGet();
                f.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
                    if(t != null) {
                        failure = t;
                        r = List.of();
                    }
                    queue.offer(r);
                    pending.decrementAndGet();
                });
            }
        }

        private boolean checkAfterSourceExhausted(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            while(pending.get() != 0 || !queue.isEmpty()) {
                checkFailure();
                try {
                    List<T> newList = queue.take();
                    fromCurrentList = newList.spliterator();
                    if(checkExisting(action)) return true;
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    throw new CompletionException(ex);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void checkFailure() {
            Throwable t = failure;
            if(t != null) {
                if(t instanceof RuntimeException rt) throw rt;
                if(t instanceof Error e) throw e;
                throw new CompletionException(t);
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
```

---

You may use something like

```java
Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>> streamOfFutures = IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .mapToObj(i -> 
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> IntStream.range(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10).boxed().toList(),
        CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(10 - i, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));

System.out.println(flattenResults(streamOfFutures)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .anyMatch(i -> i == 34)
);
```

to visualize the “first completed, first processed”. Or change the terminal operation to

```java
flattenResults(streamOfFutures).forEach(System.out::println);
```

to demonstrate the completion of all futures is correctly recognized or

```java
if(flattenResults(streamOfFutures).count() != 100)
    throw new AssertionError();
else
    System.out.println("Success");
```

to have something which can be integrated into automated test.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! The way you modeled the states of New / Existing / Exhausted resolves an issue I encountered when thinking about a similar approach - it keeps the counter from reaching zero before the original stream ends. I wonder if the exception-handling can be simplified by returning a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` instead of `Stream<T>`, as `CompletableFuture` already contains a representation of exception states.

Comment: That’s possible but not a simplification. Since this is flattening lists, returning a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` would imply wrapping each `T` in a new future. Only the failed futures would have a one-to-one relationship between source and result futures. Re counter, note that the code cares to queue items before decreasing and to recheck the queue after detecting zero which is important when the execution of both operations overlaps.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with Johannes Kuhn. You can't know Futures's state while it's still executing and thus can not convert from Stream<CompletableFuture<List>>
to Stream<CompletableFuture> .

Although the output of stream can be merged using following piece of code -
`java Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>>`  to `java List<Item>`  or

`java List<CompletableFuture<List<AuditRecord>>>`  to `java List<Item>`

```java
List<Item> output = input.map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList()).stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, this is impossible.

Consider a some arbitrary service, which will return a `CompletableFuture<Integer>`:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> getDiceRoll();
```

I can now convert this `CompletableFuture<Integer>` to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Object>>>` without any problem:

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Object>>> futureList = Stream.of(getDiceRoll().thenApply(n -> List.of(new Object[n])));
```

Let's suppose there would be a general way to turn a `Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>>` into a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>`:

```
<T> Stream<CompletableFuture<T> magic(Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> arg);
```

Then I can do the following:

```
int diceRoll = magic(Stream.of(getDiceRoll().thenApply(n -> List.of(new Object[n])))).count();
```

Wait, what?
I am now able to get an arbitrary integer out of a `CompletableFuture`.
Which means, with some engineering effort I can get all the information out of a CompletableFuture - after all, memory is just some numbers.

So we have to conclude that a method like `magic` can not exist, without violating the time fabric.
And this is the answer: There is no such method, because it can not exist.

Comment: I still don't understand this answer. I wonder if it might be easier to understand if it used `CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>` in place of `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>` and each `getDiceRoll()` had a random `sleep()` within it.

Comment: The dice roll is just for creating the `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>`. It has as many elements as the dice will roll. If a general method as you requested would exist, I could get the result of the dice roll without waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem

As I understand it, your problem can be summarized by the following:

1. You have multiple producers running concurrently. These producers are instances of `CompletableFuture`.

   - In your case, you are getting these futures from a `Stream`, but the actual source of the futures doesn't seem critical, just so long as the source is a container that can be iterated in some way.
2. You have a single consumer running concurrently with the producers. The consumer is a `Stream`.
3. You want to stay within the stream API, at least from an external perspective. In other words, you want to map `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` (the producers) to `Stream<T>` (the consumer).
4. You want to consume the result of a producer as soon as possible. No waiting to process a result because the consumer is blocked waiting for a different producer to complete.

At a fundamental level, the question seems to be how to stream the results from asynchronous computations without blocking on the futures themselves.

---

## Solution

The major hurdle to overcome here is that we don't know when a future will complete. That wouldn't matter much if you didn't care about processing results as soon as possible, because then you could just do:

```java
stream.map(CompletableFuture::join)
```

But you do care about processing results as soon as possible, and the above will wait on a future even if another one has completed. To do what you want, we'll have to use an intermediate `BlockingQueue` that each future adds its result to when complete (without blocking). Then we need another *separate* stream that reads from that queue until all results have been processed.

Here's a slightly modified version of [Holger's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260684/6395627) which:

- Can work with any `CompletionStage` implementation.
- Gives you the stage results directly instead of flattening them for you. If your results are lists, then you can just do `flatMap(List::stream)` when needed.

  - As an aside, addressing the original question, I'm of the opinion that if your results are lists, then wrapping each individual element of a list in its own `CompletableFuture` doesn't add much value. Especially since each future will have to be, by design, already completed (normally or exceptionally). If you want to launch asynchronous tasks for each element in a list, do that downstream. And if you want to handle exceptions, rather than crashing the stream on the first failure, then you can modify the below to expose the nested `Result` class (possibly modified itself) or handle the exceptions in the stages upstream (e.g., `exceptionally[Async]` or `handle[Async]` stages).
- Implements splitting based on the result of calling `trySplit()` on the source `Spliterator`.

**Note:** This replaces my old, inferior solution. You can look at the edit history to see the old solution if you want.

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class WhenCompleteSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    public static <T> Stream<T> streamResults(Iterable<? extends CompletionStage<T>> iterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new WhenCompleteSpliterator<>(iterable.spliterator()), false);
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> mapToResults(Stream<? extends CompletionStage<T>> stream) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new WhenCompleteSpliterator<>(stream.spliterator()), false);
    }

    private final BlockingQueue<Result<T>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private final AtomicLong pending = new AtomicLong();
    private Result<T> immediate;

    private final Spliterator<? extends CompletionStage<T>> upstream;
    private final long estimatedSize;

    public WhenCompleteSpliterator(Spliterator<? extends CompletionStage<T>> upstream) {
        this.upstream = Objects.requireNonNull(upstream);
        this.estimatedSize = upstream.estimateSize();
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return estimatedSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return 0; // No characteristics.
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        // Split based on upstream's ability to split.
        var upstreamSplit = upstream.trySplit();
        return upstreamSplit == null ? null : new WhenCompleteSpliterator<>(upstreamSplit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);

        // Take from queue immediately if not empty.
        if (takeFromQueue(false, action)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Consume upstream stages until all consumed or an already-completed stage is encountered.
        while (upstream.tryAdvance(this::consumeStage)) {
            if (takeImmediate(action)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Take from queue if not empty OR there are pending stages.
        if (takeFromQueue(true, action)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void consumeStage(CompletionStage<T> stage) {
        var cf = stage instanceof CompletableFuture<T> self ? self : stage.toCompletableFuture();
        if (cf.isDone()) {
            try {
                immediate = Result.ofSuccess(cf.join());
            } catch (CompletionException | CancellationException ex) {
                immediate = Result.ofFailure(ex);
            }
        } else {
            pending.incrementAndGet();
            stage.whenComplete((value, error) -> {
                queue.add(error == null ? Result.ofSuccess(value) : Result.ofFailure(error));
                pending.decrementAndGet();
            });
        }
    }

    private boolean takeFromQueue(boolean waitForPending, Consumer<? super T> action) {
        try {
            if ((waitForPending && pending.get() > 0L) || !queue.isEmpty()) {
                action.accept(queue.take().valueOrThrow());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new CompletionException("Interrupted while waiting for upstream stage result.", ex);
        }
    }

    private boolean takeImmediate(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        var immediate = this.immediate;
        if (immediate != null) {
            this.immediate = null;
            action.accept(immediate.valueOrThrow());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static class Result<T> {

        static <T> Result<T> ofSuccess(T value) {
            return new Result<>(value, null);
        }

        static <T> Result<T> ofFailure(Throwable error) {
            assert error != null;
            return new Result<>(null, error);
        }

        private final T value;
        private final Throwable error;

        private Result(T value, Throwable error) {
            this.value = value;
            this.error = error;
        }

        T valueOrThrow() {
            if (error == null) {
                return value;
            } else {
                var message = "An upstream stage completed exceptionally.";
                if (error instanceof CompletionException || error instanceof ExecutionException) {
                    var cause = error.getCause();
                    if (cause != null) {
                        // Wrap exception in new CompletionException for stack trace purposes.
                        throw new CompletionException(message, cause);
                    }
                }
                // Wrap exception in new CompletionException for stack trace purposes.
                throw new CompletionException(message, error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example using the above:

```java
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var clock = Clock.tickMillis(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();
        var futures = new Random().ints(5, 2, 30)
                .mapToObj(seconds -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.printf("[%s] Beginning %,2d second sleep!%n", LocalTime.now(clock), seconds);
                        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                        return String.format("[%s] Slept for %,2d seconds!", LocalTime.now(clock), seconds);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }, executor));
        WhenCompleteSpliterator.mapToResults(futures).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("DONE!");
    }
}
```

Note the example uses a virtual thread pool simply to ensure all "sleep tasks" are started around the same time, regardless of how many there are. A "normal" cached thread pool could do the same job (though you'd probably want to use daemon threads for the example).

And example output:

```
[22:07:24.134] Beginning 28 second sleep!
[22:07:24.132] Beginning  4 second sleep!
[22:07:24.134] Beginning 10 second sleep!
[22:07:24.133] Beginning 20 second sleep!
[22:07:24.133] Beginning  6 second sleep!
[22:07:28.166] Slept for  4 seconds!
[22:07:30.158] Slept for  6 seconds!
[22:07:34.169] Slept for 10 seconds!
[22:07:44.158] Slept for 20 seconds!
[22:07:52.160] Slept for 28 seconds!
DONE!
```

### Virtual Threads

Virtual threads won't really help with the mapping from `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` to `Stream<T>`. Though since your background tasks are I/O bound, using a virtual thread pool to execute said background tasks *might* be beneficial.

Comment: Also, I think I see the flaw in my original code: the `queue.submit(() -> ender.get());` probably executes before all the `thenApply()` consumers in the line above it.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if it still helps. Also, if you wouldn't mind, I recommend deleting most (if not all) of your existing comments under this answer to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted all outdated comments. I'll have to study your current code in more detail, especially considering it's so much more verbose than the pseudo-code at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256137/196032

Comment: Yeah, it might be a little overengineered. And some parts might be able to be simplified. Let me know if something needs clarifying. I also didn't spend too much time analyzing it or testing it, so let me know if you spot an issue as well.

Comment: If and when you accept an answer, I suggest Holger's. Their solution is more elegant than mine (as expected).

Comment: @Slaw Both of you have brought a lot of value to this site. We're blessed to have you both - neither one more than the other.

Comment: @davidalayachew Thanks, I appreciate it. Though note I'm not complaining nor disheartened. Always happy to see more elegant solutions. It's a great way to learn, and Holger is one of the top Java/JVM experts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this:
>
> `Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>>`
>
> how can I convert it to
>
> `Stream<CompletableFuture<Item>>`
>
> I looked into thenCompose but that solves a completely different problem which is also referred to as "flattening".
>
> How can this be done efficiently, in a streaming fashion, without blocking or prematurely consuming more stream items than necessary?

This is absolutely possible, but long story short, it will save you no work, it will add overhead in ways that provide you no benefit, and will actually make your code slower in the long run. You will have accomplished nothing of value by doing this.

The reason for this is simple -- `CompletableFuture` operates on a [push-down design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421639/10118965). Meaning, the ***INSTANT*** you attempt to attach a chaining call (`thenApply`, `thenCompose`, etc) or a complete call (`get`, `join`, `complete`), `CompletableFuture` will IMMEDIATELY start computation. It may be easier to think of `CompletableFuture` to being eager evaluation the moment that you chain a follow-up function to it. Not every follow up function will trigger computation, but all of the useful ones will.

What this means is that, the second you try to even touch (metaphorically) a `CompletableFuture`, you have triggered it to start computing. And this computation is "necessary", so it still meets your requirements.

I am happy to go into detail about why the function you wanted to call on the `CompletableFuture<Item>` would either be the same impact as just fetching from the `CompletableFuture<List<Item>>`, or would be even more expensive and slower for no benefit. Please tell me, then I will amend this answer and explain exactly why your desired function will not help you in any useful way, other than being the form that you like for whatever arbitrary reason.

Regardless, if this is truly what you want, then here is how.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SOQ_20230926
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
   
      record Item(int index) {}
   
      final Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>> pointA =
         create
         (
            List
               .of
               (
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)),
                  List.of(new Item(4), new Item(5), new Item(6)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9)),
                  List.of(new Item(7), new Item(8), new Item(9))
               )
         )
         ;
   
      final Stream<CompletableFuture<Item>> pointZ = convert(pointA);
   
      final Item item =
         pointZ
            .parallel()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .filter(eachItem -> eachItem.index() == 4)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow()
            ;
   
      System.out.println(item);
   
   }

   private static <T> Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> convert(final Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> pointA)
   {
   
      return
         pointA
            .parallel()
            .map
            (
               eachFuture ->
                  eachFuture
                     .thenApply
                     (
                        batch ->
                           batch
                              .parallelStream()
                              .map(eachElement -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> eachElement))
                              .toList()
                     )
            )
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            ;
   
   }

   private static <T> Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> create(final List<List<T>> lists)
   {
   
      return
         lists
            .parallelStream()
            .map
            (
               eachList ->
                  CompletableFuture
                     .supplyAsync
                     (
                        () ->
                        {
                        
                           System.out.println("COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED");
                        
                           return eachList;
                        
                        }
                     )
         
            )
            ;
   
   }

}
```

And here is the output.

```
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED
Item[index=4]
```

As you can see, the `Stream` "stopped early", only doing the work necessary to find the `Item` it needed.

If it had done more work than needed, we would have seen all 54 lines of `COMPUTATION WAS PERFORMED`, but we only see 31, because that was all that was needed to find our value. The rest of the batches remained unopened because we found what we needed.

This should meet your 2 requirements. Those are the following.

> I have this:
>
> `Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>>`
>
> how can I convert it to
>
> `Stream<CompletableFuture<Item>>`

> How can this be done efficiently, in a streaming fashion, without blocking or prematurely consuming more stream items than necessary?

Comment: Interesting response. We have some different assumptions at play here. Per the Java documentation, `CompletableFuture` _represents a future result of an asynchronous computation_. Your code uses a synthetic CompletableFuture that's not asynchronous at all. The original question is based on the premise that the `CompletableFuture`s run asynchronously, i.e. autonomously in some other thread(s), as afforded in the Java documentation. I'll clarify this in the question.

Comment: @AlexR I'm going to need more info than that. What part of my answer do you take issue with? Do you dislike the call to `CompletableFuture::completedFuture`? That can easily be swapped out with `CompletableFuture::supplyAsync` instead. Do you take issue with something else entirely?

Comment: specifically your test-case does not contain any asynchronous processing, and so it does not demonstrate how to efficiently wait for a stream of lists of asynchronous processes to complete.

Comment: @AlexR Oh that's incredibly easy. See where I put `sequential()`? Change that to parallel. It is now running asynchronously.

Comment: @AlexR Please note, making it asynchronous means that you will not get deterministic behaviour. So, it will not always iterate through only the elements it needs to. It will sometimes go a little further than expected, since it is running asynchronously, and thus, checking multiple other lists while checking the one it is currently on.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include both of the changes @AlexR

Comment: Thank you. I need to review this code a little more carefully.

Comment: I don't think this code is correct. I believe the way to prevent blocking would be to spawn a thread for each item in the List as each List becomes available, then have threads populate a queue which in turn is drained by another Stream.

Comment: @AlexR If you did that, you would actually be ***slower*** than my solution. What you have just described is essentially recreating what `Strem::parallel` does. `Stream::parallel` does something similar to what you described, but it uses a Spliterator, which allows it to make a judgement call over when you should and SHOULD NOT use parallelism. If you just indiscriminately threads to grab each element, you would lose performance.

Comment: Now, if you want to squeeze every drop of performance out of this (and the lists in question are MASSIVE), I could add a few more `Stream::parallel` calls, which would help recreate what you seem to want, but again, it does it conditionally, and only when it proves to itself that it would be beneficial to do so. I have updated my answer to include parallel calls wherever possible.

Comment: And even then, I actually have made my solution slower now in certain circumstances. If those sublists are small enough, then my decision to add a parallel call will actually make things slower than if I had done it sequentially. That conditional judgement call I talked about doesn't always get things right, so switching to all parallel like I just did should only ever be done when it is proven that it is faster. With performance tests.

Comment: The only reason we should ever use parallelism is if we can get a speed boost. If we do not get the speed boost over sequential, then parallelism does literally nothing good for you. So do not tie yourself to concepts such as blocking and non-blocking. Tie yourself to the reality of "does this strategy speed up my performance or not?" And it is ***ONLY WHEN YOU KNOW THE ANSWER TO THAT QUESTION*** should you then dig into the next question of "Why?" If you do not follow this order of operations, you run the risk of making false assumptions.

Comment: But all that said, after adding all those parallel calls, my solution truly is now non-blocking, even if it is at the detriment of the performance in certain edge cases. I would really love to learn what use case led to you having such strange and contradictory requirements. This whole question may just be an XY problem -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: This scenario came up in a project that I worked on 4 years ago, and I no longer have the details of the use-case. But I still think it was a valid question, and I decided to revisit it now that Java 21 has come out with the virtual threads feature which should make this possible. The answer from Nishika is the most insightful: "_You can't know Futures's state while it's still executing_" - and that's the path to a solution. If we can create a virtual thread to monitor the each Future, it becomes possible to know each Future's completion state just in time to drive a stream of completions.

Comment: Thanks again for the deep discussion on this. Please note that the commentary regarding the parallel solution being slower is really not applicable here, because I seem to have left out an important assumption: the asynchronous tasks which are referenced in the Stream of Lists are I/O-bound, not CPU-bound. Apologies for not making this clear initially. I'll add it as a clarification.

Comment: @AlexR Respectfully, that's pretty much the most important detail to leave out. It seems it really was an XY Problem. If that is true, then yes, you no longer care about speed at all, you care about ***throughput***. In that situation, a virtual thread per task makes sense. That is actually the officially suggested solution when you are willing to sacrifice speed in order to get throughput. Understanding that now, the question then becomes - ***how much*** speed are you willing to sacrifice to get throughput? Because, depending on the answer will decide which solution is best.

Comment: If you are 100% certain that you have enough memory, CPU, network bandwidth (and maybe disk space, depending on if you need to store some of it locally) to handle this task at its worst, then virtual thread per task makes the most sense. But, if any of the above becomes false, then you need to start making changes. For example, how frequently are these requests coming in? Is it possible to have 2 requests being processed simultaneously, or can they only occur 1 after the other? What about the concurrency? Do you have other tasks besides this use case running on the same machine?

Comment: And don't forget about the actual task at hand. What are you actually doing? Are you trying to find the first occurrence of a certain something? Are you looking for a number of them? Is there a "likely candidate"? All of these are questions that would influence the answer. As a result, a question like yours would be a much better fit for Code Review Stack Exchange, with the full context and code provided. That way, someone can help critique the strengths and weaknesses of your current solution. A virtual thread per task is a good starting point, but it will likely need to be iterated upon.

Comment: Neither speed or throughput were an original requirement. The question was _How can this be done efficiently, in a streaming fashion, without blocking or prematurely consuming more stream items than necessary?_

Comment: @AlexR To be perfectly frank, your requirements were contradictory in and of themselves. You want a stream that does not block, and yet, you don't want to prematurely consume more items than necessary. Those are contradictory requirements. Either we must do some unnecessary work (firing off a virtual thread per task, even though some of the tasks are stream items we will end up not caring about) or we will block.

Comment: That said, contradictory requirements are common on this site. So, the best I (and others answering) could come up with was that you wanted efficiency, and you thought that getting it via that Stream of futures was somehow faster. So, we all gave our best suggestions, but we all acknowledged that it still won't get you what you likely really want, at least, not as your question phrased it.

Comment: Well then. The other two answers saying it's impossible may be correct. I'll study the long answer form Johannes Kuhn again to try to understand his reasoning.

Comment: @AlexR If it were me, I would make a brand new question with the necessary context, then ping the 2 others above, and let them know. You'll probably get an answer that better addresses your true goals. Also link it to me as well. Of course, if you are happy with any of the answers we provided, then that works too.

Comment: TBH, I think the question shows a profound misunderstanding I had over how Streams work. In my mind at the time I asked, I should have been able to use a Stream of Futures in places where I really needed a Nonblocking Queue. A new question would not properly express this confusion, and would be a different question.

Comment: @AlexR Oh by all means, remove the misunderstandings, and you get a different question. That's my point - it sounded like you might still have a question that none of our answers have addressed. If so, feel free to raise a new question.

Comment: Hi David, I think the original question deserves an answer. Either it's impossible, or the question has an incorrect premise, or there is a clever way (which I was attempting in my original code, please have a look at that again). I've added +100 bounty points. Also think about this - if I remove the misunderstandings, there is no question left to ask, is there?

Comment: @AlexR Misunderstandings was not the right word for me to use, but I understand your point. Taking a look now.

Comment: @AlexR LOL yes, I can answer this question. I never would have originally guessed that this is what your original question was asking. Rather than editing this answer, I'll simply submit a new answer.

Comment: @AlexR I'll finish my answer tomorrow or something. But spoiler alert, now that I understand that this is your question, the answer is to use `ExecutorService::newVirtualThreadPerTask`. I'll go into more detail once I get a chance to finish this thing. Ideally tomorrow.

Comment: "_will IMMEDIATELY start computation_" – Not really. The only stages that start an actual computation immediately, at least in the standard API, are `supplyAsync` and `runAsync`. You can have an entire chain/tree of stages all rooted with one built via `new CompletableFuture<>()` and nothing will actually happen until that root stage is completed "manually" (or some other stage in the chain/tree is completed, but that will only cause further computations in that stage's descendants, not any of its ancestors or stages in entirely separate branches).

Comment: @Slaw touche. I'm actually going to delete this answer because I think the other answers have captured what I wanted to say.

Comment: @AlexR The bounty has brought in a lot of new answers, some of which have already said what I wanted to. I'll delete my answer and encourage you to read through those.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some **pseudo-code** of what I'm thinking now after conversation with @Slaw:

```
public class StreamTest {

    static <T> Stream<T> flattenResults(Stream<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> stream) {
        List<T> EOL = new ArrayList<>();
        BlockingQueue<List<T>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        Thread thread = Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
            stream.forEach(future -> future.thenAcceptAsync(queue::offer));

            // this pseudo-code method ensures EOL is not added prematurely
            blockUntilAllAcceptAsyncsHaveExecuted();

            queue.offer(EOL);
        });

        return Stream.generate(() -> {
                    try {
                        return queue.poll(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .stopWhen(i -> i == EOL) // this method doesn't exist!
                .filter(i -> i != EOL)
                .flatMap(List::stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not ensure that `queue.offer(EOL)` is done after the other `offer` calls. Further, `List.of()` might (and does in practice) return a shared object that may also occur as a normal result from one of the futures.

Comment: Thanks, I made some fixes. Please note my own answer is not acceptable because it is pseudo-code that references things that don't exist.

Comment: Well, there’s [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) which you can use instead of the non-existing `stopWhen`; you just have to negate the condition. The `blockUntilAllAcceptAsyncsHaveExecuted()` could be implemented using `CompletableFuture.allOf` but when you use `allOf`, you can chain a `whenComplete(x -> queue.offer(EOL))` in the first place, then you don’t need a virtual thread. Still, it implies eagerly traversing the entire source stream which my answer’s solution avoids.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed, but I'd still like to give my variation of Nishika's answer with a slight repositioning:

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<List<Item>>> origStream = // ...
// make streams out of the lists first
final Stream<CompletableFuture<Stream<Item>>> streamFutures =
             origStream.map(f -> f.thenApply(Collection::stream));
```

This makes it clearer that the actual item streams of the individual futures can only be retrieved when their completion stage is finished.

Additionally, you'll only be able to `flatMap` these streams by again waiting for the individual completion, ie `join`ing on the futures. So now you can just do:

```
final Stream<Item> itemStream = streamFutures.flatMap(CompletableFuture::join);
```

You can make a `CompletableFuture` out of this:

```
final CompletableFuture<Stream<Item>> itemStreamFuture =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> streamFutures.flatMap(CompletableFuture::join));
```

but you hardly gain any concurrency except the call isn't blocking. I'd wager the `join`s themselves are handled concurrently if the stream is created as parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In your update4 you say:

> How can you take a Stream that's produced in arbitrary order, and re-order it into futures execution completion order, so that a flatMap() operation will not block unnecessaril

Suppose u have 3 futures that completes in 2, 5 and 10 seconds accordingly and u wants some `method` that returns an ordered by execution time stream, so in this way u have to wait until all futures are done (or fail) because until u dont know is future is done or fail u dont know how long was execution time.
You can create ordered stream of results with blocking:

```java
    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    private static final ExecutorService consumerService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final AtomicInteger ID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final List<DelayedListSupplier> completionOrder = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class DelayedListSupplier implements Supplier<List<String>> {
        private final int delayMs;
        private final int id;

        @Override
        public List<String> get() {
            try {
                if (random.nextInt(10) < 2) {
                    System.out.println(
                            String.format(
                                    "Thread [%s]; Future %s FAILED.",
                                    Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                                    id
                            )
                    );
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error!" + id);
                }
                Thread.sleep(delayMs);
                System.out.println(
                        String.format(
                                "Thread [%s]; Future %s is completed.",
                                Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                                id
                        )
                );
                //just for SOUT
                completionOrder.add(this);
                return List.of("Future" + id);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start blocking");
        blockingAnswer();
        System.out.println("Start non blocking");
        nonBlockingAnswer();
        executorService.shutdown();
        consumerService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        consumerService.shutdown();
    }

    private static void nonBlockingAnswer() {
        List<DelayedListSupplier> delayedSuppliers = createDelayedSuppliers();
        Stream<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futuresStream = getFutures(delayedSuppliers);
        futuresStream.forEachOrdered(cf -> {
            cf.whenComplete((r,e) -> {
                if (e == null) {
                    consumerService.execute(() -> {
                        //handle results here
                        System.out.println("Recevied results from future" + r.get(0));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private static void blockingAnswer() throws InterruptedException {
        //prepare futures
        List<DelayedListSupplier> suppliers = createDelayedSuppliers();
        //map them to CompletableFuture
        Stream<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> cf = getFutures(suppliers);
        List<List<String>> results = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());

        //we need collect futures for using CountDownLatch
        List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futures = cf.collect(Collectors.toList());

        int maxWaitTime = suppliers.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(DelayedListSupplier::getDelayMs))
                .map(DelayedListSupplier::getDelayMs)
                .orElseThrow();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //for method exit we need to N futures completed or failed
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch((int) futures.size());
        futures.forEach(f -> {
            //add post-execution logic for each future
            f.whenComplete((r, e) -> {
                cdl.countDown();
                //if no exception this is actual result
                if (e == null) {
                    results.add(r);
                }
            });
        });

        //wait until each future will done or 1000 days
        cdl.await(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "Execution time: %s ms; Max wait time: %s",
                        end - start,
                        maxWaitTime
                )
        );
        System.out.println("Future Results: " + completionOrder.stream().map(s -> "" + s.getId()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

        //our result stream here
        Stream<String> resultStream = results.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream);
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "FlatMap: %s",
                        resultStream.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                )
        );
    }

    private static List<DelayedListSupplier> createDelayedSuppliers() {
        List<DelayedListSupplier> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            suppliers.add(
                    new DelayedListSupplier(
                            (random.nextInt(6) + 1) * 1000,
                            ID.incrementAndGet()
                    )
            );
        }
        return suppliers;
    }

    private static Stream<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> getFutures(List<DelayedListSupplier> suppliers) {
        return suppliers.stream()
                .map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s, executorService));
    }
```

For non blocking at all u have to use *Producer/Consumer* pattern (see in method *nonBlockingAnswer*)

Comment: Assume 3 futures that completes in 2, 5 and 10 seconds but processing takes an additional 4 seconds each. This code will complete in 22 seconds `(max(2,5,10) + 4*count([2,5,10])`, but the goal is to complete in 14 seconds `(max(2+4,5+4,10+4))`. Now if you add processing in a `thenAsync()` method, your solution would be pretty close, it's just missing a final step to return a `Stream`.

Comment: Nope blockingAnswer() completes in max of future delay, cause using countdown latch for blocking, try run it

Comment: Hmm im not noticed "processing each", so if each processing is 4 sec then you need 3 threads anyway for achieve a total time of 14