# How to create a CompletableFuture that does not compute until CompletableFuture::get is called?

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation, completable-future

The title is mostly self-explanatory. I am trying to solve a question, but in order to do so, I need the `CompletableFuture` to NOT attempt execution until someone starts running it via `CompletableFuture::get`.

I am prepared to switch to another class if need be, but I wanted to ask here first.

I guess the proper term for this would be lazy evaluation of a `CompletableFuture`.

The spirit of my request is similar to this --  [`Thread.Builder::unstarted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.Builder.html#unstarted(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: This question seems backward to me; an unstarted CompletableFuture is actually the default (it's what the constructor gives you). I guess your real question is how to make `CompletableFuture.get()` trigger a computation?

Comment: does the CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() fulfill your requirements? I think it should take a supplier and only when you call get will it process the supplier to return whatever result, or maybe you could use a supplier to supply a CompletableFuture instead?

Comment: @ruakh Maybe I am making a bad assumption here. Yes, the question you are positing also meets my needs. If you are able to turn that into an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I am actually starting from that point, and it didn't work. That was the first thing I tried. If you know how to construct an unstarted CompletableFuture, and then provide it a Supplier, that I would accept.

Comment: @ruakh You sent me down the right path. I ended up figuring out the answer. If you want to type up the answer, I'll accept yours. If not, let me know and I will type up my own, as this is fairly non-obvious to me.

Comment: @ruakh Actually, I only half answered my own question. If you are able to construct your answer, I would appreciate it. For how to start execution upon a call to get().

Comment: I feel that a `CompletableFuture` in its unstarted state does not contain the logic it needs to run. it's something like an unstarted thread without a `Runnable` or overridden `run()`. `get()` simply "*Waits [...] to complete, and then returns its result*". Reactive streams on the other hand work this way, i.e. contain the logic to be executed and may wait for a subscriber before starting (the cold variety). You may want to take a look at RX Java or Mutiny - e.g. check out [the introduction to Uni](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.5.0/tutorials/creating-uni-pipelines/#the-uni-type).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos If it's simply not possible, then I accept that. At the end of the day, I just want to confirm that before moving forward. If you can claim definitively that it is impossible, post and answer with evidence and I will accept it if it holds up.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Doesn't seem like it, no. I think ruakh put it best - I want computation to start when calling CompletableFuture::get. I'll edit my question to say as much, since that seems far more inline with what I want.

Comment: @davidalayachew I found this which seems very similar to what you are looking for. Take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421347/16034206

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Indeed it is, ty. In that case, my question is a duplicate. Please flag it accordingly.

Comment: The contract of the `get()` method is wait for the completion and return the result. When you combine this with the idea to start the computation when `get()` is called, you have no future but just a synchronous computation. In other words, you then just have a `Supplier` so use `Supplier` in the first place.

Comment: @Holger That is a solid argument for why this functionality is not supported. Ty vm.